# how to kill a ssh script running?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, debian

I have this script running on my server

```
for i in {1..400000}
do
   echo "loop $i"
   echo 
   numberps=`ps -ef | grep php | wc -l`;
   echo $numberps
   if [ $numberps -lt 110 ]
   then
   php5 script.php &
   sleep 0.25
   else
     echo too much process
    sleep 0.5
fi
done
```

It is lunched with

```
./script.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

it opens up to 110 php processes.

I can kill the processes

I can kill the php5 processes with `killall -9 php5`

But the script will create them again:

**How can I stop the script ONCE it is lunched ?**

`kill %1` : this works great when I am loggedon to SSH
If I loggedout and login again, `kill %1` or `jobs -l` does not work any more.

Comment: What does `ssh` have to do with this?

Comment: `for i in {1..400000}` will expand to a large memory; prefer `for ((i=1; i<=400000; i++))`

Comment: @EdouardThiel It would use less than 1MB.

Comment: `echo {1..400000}|wc -c` gives 2688895, which is quite a waste of memory for a simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch the script, the shell will print something like:

```
[1] 1219
```

The number in brackets is the *job number*, the second number is the *PID*. You can kill the whole job with:

```
$ kill %1
```

If you don't remember the job number, you can use the `jobs` command to get a list:

```
$ jobs
[1]+ Running ./script.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

The job number is again the number in brackets. Put `%` before it to kill it.

Comment: `jobs -l` gives the jobs and their PID.

Comment: I loggedon and typed jobs -l
Gives NOTHING (it is runnign now !)

any way to put the job id into 'currentJob.txt' file text ?

Comment: besides "jobs -l" works ONLY when I am loggedon to SSH. 
When I loggedout and login again kill %1 does not work any more

Comment: Job control only works when the process is a child of the current shell. And unless you used `nohup`, the process should have been killed when you logged out. If you want to be able to keep a shell session when disconnecting, take a look at `screen`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "To stop, type: kill -USR1 $$"

main_loop=true
catch_sigusr1 () { main_loop=false ;}
trap catch_sigusr1 SIGUSR1

for ((i=1; i<=400000; i++))
do
   $main_loop || { echo "Aborting script."; break ;}
   echo "loop $i"
   echo 
   numberps=`ps -ef | grep php | wc -l`;
   echo $numberps
   if [ $numberps -lt 110 ]
   then
   php5 script.php &
   sleep 0.25
   else
     echo too much process
    sleep 0.5
fi
done
```

Comment: I typed in: kill -USER1 $$ THIS LOGGED me OUT and I cannot end jobs any more with kill %1

Comment: try `kill -USR1 pid` instead of `kill -USER1 pid`.

Comment: I tried: no success.. Problem porbably comes from that I lunch this command, then logout with  'exit' command, then come back to SSH.